# how to make search result group by host in nutch

Tags: java, nutch

i am making an small intranet search i use nutch for crawling and searching
i have sub-domains like

```
z.example.com
a.example.com
m.example.com
```

and if i search some value using nutch i am getting search result from all domains i need one result per sub domain

Answer (score 0):

You could make 3 queries using site:"foo.example.com" field. Is that good enough for your use case ?